# Scenes are squishing when switching

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[before I switch scenes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0MLL.png)                  [after I switch scenes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJM9.png)
my name is Julian. Recently I've been getting into coding with swift and Xcode, but have ran into some problems when switching scenes. For example, in this game I'm currently working on there are two scenes, the TitleScene, and the GameScene. When the user loads the app it will start in the TitleScene, and there'll be a button that says "Start Game". When the user clicks on the "Start Game" button it will run the code,

```
`let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(),         duration: 0.1)
    self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: transition)

    gameSceneButton.hidden = true
```

`

then the scene switches to the GameScene. Once the user dies in the game two more buttons will appear, one saying "Restart" and the other "Main Menu". When the user taps the "Main Menu" button it will run the code,

```
    `let scene = TitleScene(fileNamed: "TitleScene")
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(),   duration: 0.1)
    self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: transition)
    restartButton.removeFromSuperview()
    mainMenuButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

`
once the code is ran, and the TitleScene loads, the scene becomes squished vertically

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Comment: is that good? @KirkBeard